# change the size of the parent div according to the children divs in it

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with a `div` not changing its height, which is not set in CSS, when its inner content (like `ul`, other `div`s, etc) changes.

my html code:

```
<div id="main_wrapper"> 
    <div id="navigation"> 
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"> link one </a></li> 
            <li><a href="#"> link two </a></li> 
            <li><a href="#"> link three </a></li> 
            <li><a href="#"> link four </a></li> 
        </ul> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

my css code:

```
#main_wrapper { 
  display: block;
  border:1px solid black; 
} 
#navigation { 
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); 
  position: relative;  
  padding: 8px; 
  float: right; 
}
```

demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NXNDV/)

Answer (score 2):

Add `overflow: auto;` to `#main_wrapper`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the `div` is not taking the height of the elements inside it has to do with a quirk of displaying floated elements. Adding an empty element after the `#navigation` element with `clear: both;` as a style will cause `#main_wrapper` to fit the height of the floated element.

Alternatively, you can add `display: inline-block;` to the wrapper `div`, but you will also have to specify the width (`width: 100%;`). Using the clearfix is the preferred solution.

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/NXNDV/4/